# Pause Velocity animation in the middle

Tags: javascript, jquery, velocity.js

I am trying out Velocity (https://github.com/julianshapiro/velocity) to power some animations (not using CSS animation because I need some more control over it). Say I am translating a block using:

```
$element.velocity({
    translateX: "100vh"
});
```

Is there are way to stop the animation in the middle of transition in its current position? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since version 1.4 VelocityJS has had pause/resume abilities, the documentation hasn't been updated to match, but simply use `"pause"` or `"resume"` as arguments on an element list -

```
$element.velocity("pause");
```

and later -

```
$element.velocity("resume");
```